# R Error in adding leading zeros through function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm coding to update values with leading zeros for multiple datasets. I figured it is easier to wrap the code in a function:

```
convert_scs <- function(df, state,county,street) {

  df$state <- ifelse( nchar(df$state) == 1, paste('0', df$state, sep=''), df$state )

  df$county <- ifelse( nchar(df$county) == 1, paste('00',df$county, sep=''), df$county )
  df$county <- ifelse( nchar(df$county) == 2, paste('0', df$county, sep=''), df$county )

  df$street <- ifelse( (nchar(df$street) == 3) ,  paste('000', df$street, sep=''),  df$street)
  df$street <- ifelse( (nchar(df$street) == 4) ,  paste('00', df$street, sep=''),  df$street)
  df$street <- ifelse( (nchar(df$street) == 5) ,  paste('0', df$street, sep=''),  df$street)

  return(df)

}


convert_scs(predicted20,STATEFP,COUNTYFP, STREETCE)
```

predicted20 has been converted to dataframe by using:

```
predicted20 <- as.data.frame(predicted20)
```

I kept on getting the following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "state", value = logical(0)) : 
>   replacement has 0 rows, data has 1200

There are no missings in the dataset.

Any help will be appreciated!

A sample of predicted20

Sample data before:

```
STATEFP(char)  COUNTYFP(char)   STREETCF(char)
1                    1              20100
1                    1              10500
1                    3              11502
```

Need it to be:

```
STATEFP(char)  COUNTYFP(char)   STREETCF(char)
01                    001              020100
01                    001              010500
01                    003              011502
```

Answer (score 1):

We   can replace the `$`  with`[[` inside the function

```
convert_scs <- function(df, state,county,street) {

  df[[state]] <- ifelse( nchar(df[[state]]) == 1, paste('0', df[[state]], sep=''), df[[state]]
 )

  df[[county]] <- ifelse( nchar(df[[county]]) == 1, paste('00',df[[county]], sep=''), df[[county]] )
 df[[county]] <- ifelse( nchar(df[[county]])  == 2, paste('0',df[[county]] , sep=''),df[[county]]  )

  df[[street]] <- ifelse( (nchar(df[[street]] ) == 3) ,  paste('000',  df[[street]],  sep=''),  df[[street]] )
  df[[street]]  <- ifelse( (nchar( df[[street]] ) == 4) ,  paste('00',  df[[street]] , sep=''),  df[[street]] )
  df[[street]] <- ifelse( (nchar( df[[street]] ) == 5) ,  paste('0',  df[[street]],  sep=''),   df[[street]] )

  df

}
```

and the pass the column names as strings in  the function

```
convert_scs(predicted20,'STATEFP','COUNTYFP', 'STREETCF')
#    STATEFP COUNTYFP STREETCF
#1      01      001   020100
#2      01      001   010500
#3      01      003   011502
```

---

Also, this can be done much easily with `sprintf`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
predicted20 %>%
   map2_df(.,  c("%02d", "%03d", "%06d"), ~ sprintf(fmt = .y, .x))
```

Or in `base R`

```
predicted20[] <-  Map(sprintf, predicted20, fmt = c("%02d", "%03d", "%06d"))
```

#### data

```
predicted20 <- structure(list(STATEFP = c(1L, 1L, 1L), COUNTYFP = c(1L, 1L, 
3L), STREETCF = c(20100L, 10500L, 11502L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: The new error: Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'STATEFP' not found

Comment: @lydias  DO you have a matrix or `data.frame`  I  assume that you already converted to `data.frame` `predicted20 <- as.data.frame(predicted20)`

Comment: I have a data.frame. The function did run after I added quotation marks around the argument in the calling function, but no leading zero were added to the column values...

Comment: @lydias Can you  update with a  small reproducible example.  Without  data or  strucuttre, it is  not clear

Comment: @lydias I find in one of the case, the `nchar`  bracket was not closed.  Can you  try now

Comment: in your code there are missing commas before seps. My code is working fine outside of the function. There should not be any missing bracket.

Comment: for some reason the leading zeros still do not appear in the value

Comment: the value only changes by using "$" without a function. It is very strange, and I made sure I converted it to dataframe.

Comment: @lydias  It is not advisable to use `$` within a function.  If you cannot show an example, it is hard to pinpoint the reason

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @lydias  I am getting the prefix 0s.  Please check my update.  Note that I removed the `(char)` at the end of each column name asuming that you have used it as some kind of reference

Comment: my imported variables are in the format of character. Yours are in int.

Comment: @Lydias  Okay, in that case, you can just convert to `numeric` i.e. `predicted20 <- type.convert(predicted20)` and then apply the function

Comment: thanks for the help, but sometime the variables will not stay right next to each other, I need to refer them by column names. Sprintf may not work in that case. I still cannot get the code to work even by using your generated dataset, predicted20. I feel the function is not returning anything to replace the old dataset..

Comment: @lydias If you have column names, then just subset the data by column names and then update it. i.e. `nm1 <- c("STATEFP", "COUNTYFP", "'STREETCF"); predicted20[nm1] <- Map(sprintf, predicted20[nm1], fmt = c("%02d", "%03d", "%06d"))`